# Foreach doesnt display data on the page after the data was loaded and mapped with ko.mapped knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I get data, mapped it with ko.mapping and try to display on the page. Unfortunately I do not see it on the page. I am able to assess and see values in Chrome developer console, but not on the page.

Getting and mapping values:

```
var viewModel = {};

define(['knockout', 'mapping', 'jquery'], function (ko, mapping, $) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Board = ko.observable();

    Board.prototype.setData = function (data) {
        Board = mapping.fromJS(data, {}, Board);
    }; 
        viewModel = new Board();

        //gets data and sets it by calling viewModel.setData(data)
        connectToServer1(); 

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
});
```

Displaying values on the page:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach:  viewModel.People">
          <div data-bind="text:$index"></div>
          <div data-bind="text:lastName"></div>      
 </div>
```

If I put in console viewModel. People(), I see my array of data. Very confused why it is not working on the page. Thank you

Updated:

I really want to use ko.mapping instead of manually mapping properties. Unfortunately, the only way I am able to see data on the page, it is when I removed ko.mapping and have:

```
var viewModel = {};

define(['knockout',  'jquery'], function (ko,  $) {
$(document).ready(function () {
 viewModel = {
    format : ko.observable(),
    place: ko.observable(),
    people : ko.observableArray()
};

viewModel.setData = function (data) {
   viewModel.people(data.People);
   viewModel.place(data.Place);
   viewModel.format(data.Format);
};

connectToServer1();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

   });
  });
```

Comment: Board is an observable, not a constructor

Answer (score 0):

You have conflated your viewmodel constructor with the observable you want to have in your viewmodel. Using a constructor and a prototype for a viewmodel is overcomplicating things; you're not likely to have more than one. This should be right:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var viewModel = {
    board: ko.observable(),
    setData: function(data) {
      mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel.board);
    }
  };

  //gets data and sets it by calling viewModel.setData(data)
  connectToServer1();

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Update: You will probably have to modify things so that the initial mapping and subsequent mappings use different forms. [See docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#example-using-komapping).

Comment: viewModel.board doesnt get updated once viewModel.setData(data) is called in connectToServer1(). When I step through and get to setData, data variable holds correct values, but viewModel.board still stays undefined. Can it be because data is complex multinested object?

Comment: Also if to remove viewModel.board completly, and set viewModel itself to data, then I can see values in console, but once again not on page

     $(document).ready(function () {
       viewModel = {
    board: ko.observable(),
    setData: function(data) {
      viewModel=mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel);
      console.log(viewModel.Players());
    }
  };

        connectToServer1();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    });